# Duende IdentityServer 6 - find out whether user provided password or was recognized

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, identityserver4, openid-connect, duende-identity-server

Is there a way to tell, whether the user needed to login with username and passwort on the Duende Identity Server 6, or whether he was recognized (by the ASP.NET Core Session Cookie) and the login was automatically done? Ideal would be a specific line in the code of Identity Server, where this is checked.

Comment: Could you please tell me what you mean about the the login was automatically done? Do you mean its token is already inside the cookie? If this is your requirement, I think it doesn't contain this information, since after login successfully, it will also set the token inside the cookie to avoid login multiple times.

Comment: @BrandoZhang 1. the client finds that it has no cookie, is not authenticated. 2. it starts the Open ID Connect Flow by redirecting to the ID Server. 3. The ID Server checks if it has a cookie. If it does, then the user does not need to reenter credentials. If it doesn't the user has to provide username and password. 4. The ID Server issues an authcode to the client. Now as the client I want to tell whether the user had to enter the credentials or if the ID Server had already a cookie and recognized the logged in user. But how can the client find this out?